# How do I plot given coordinates on a different image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, a-star

I have used the A* algorithm to get coordinates of a given path between two points on an array.
I now want to use those given return coordinates, import an image and plot the line on the image

this is my given path, although its not x=1 y=13, its row 1 column 13 etc

```
data = np.array([
  [1, 13], [2, 1], [3, 13],
  [4, 13], [5, 13],[6, 12],
 [7, 12], [8, 12], [9, 13],
[10, 13], [11, 14], [12, 14], 
[13, 14], [14, 14], [15, 15],
[16, 16]
])
```

I have an image that looks like a ROS lidar map I want to plot it on, any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to plot a path (`data`) on a given map/image? Or are you trying to plot a path on its own?

Comment: @QuangHoang trying to plot a path on a given map and display that path

Comment: You can use `plt.imshow()` to plot the map, and then plot the path on that map.

Comment: @QuangHoang so do plt.imshow("test.jpg) to pull in the image? and then how do I put the points on the image with the line?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend exploring the OpenCV library and its python bindings. I've used it before to draw bounding boxes on image regions, which is pretty similar to the use case here.

Comment: btw, if you are working with rasters I would take a look at the rasterio library, it's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is [cv.polylines](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c).
Its a convinient function where you can feed in the points through which you want the trajectory to be plotted as well as the image and drawing parameters with which the image has to be updated with the polylines plot.

Hope this helps..